# How to set the layout directly in designer?

Tags: qt4

I would like to set up the layout for a widget directly, as I didn't find a way to do it in the UI editor, I often turns to:

`ui->tab->setLayout (ui->verticalLayout)`

But that looks stupid to me.

Is there anyway to do that without extra coding?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the widget you want in your editor and choose the layout you want to use in the menu :
[image: layout selection]

There is no need to add a layout inside a widget in the editor.